# I could select an image from gallery in android. But, i want to select next and previous images of the selected image. How do i do it?

Tags: android, image

I could select an image from gallery in android. But, i want to select next and previous images of the selected image. How do i do it?

This works fine.. for selecting and then displaying the image..now what do i do for selecting next and previous images?

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });


@Override
             protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                     Uri uri = data.getData();

                     try {
                         Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                         // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

                         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I could select an image from gallery in android

Your code *happens* to bring up a gallery app on your device. You are requesting `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for `image/*`. This means:

- Other apps, besides a gallery, can respond to that `Intent` and can be chosen by the user
- There will be devices that do not have an app that would be considered a "gallery"

> How do i do it?

Write your own gallery. There is no concept of "next" or "previous" with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

There are many [image picker libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/157) that might form the basis for your own gallery UI.

Comment: can u plz help me more, by writing some code here. please? This is my first app.. and i have been working on it since long.. i want to write the code foe going to next and previous images.. and according to u, i'm also ready to create my own gallery.. but i'm quite fade up this time. Thank u for the above help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to write the most important thing, which is code for previous and next is not working.. till now i have written code only for previous, coz once it works; next ll be just few changes ahead.

moveToprevious is coming false n cursor is declared as global.. so that when a query for cusor s fired in getcontentresolver() is fired, it gets the needed value..

Please look into this!